# Groovy 4 trait: MissingMethodException on calling existing static method during runtime

Tags: inheritance, methods, groovy, static, traits

In trait (after upgrading to Groovy 4.0.8 from 2.5) MissingMethodException is thrown inside method called from closure.

**Groovy Console**

```
TestClass.getLevel1() // run test

class TestClass implements TestTrait{}

trait TestTrait{
    static getLevel1(){  println(['getLevel1':this])
        getLevel2('good') // runs
        def me = this
        'bad'.with{me.getLevel2(it)} // runs
        'ugly'.with{getLevel2(it)} // throws getLevel3 not found
    }
    static getLevel2(String s){  println(['getLevel2':this])
        getLevel3(s) // throws MissingMethodException for 'ugly'
    }
    static getLevel3(String s){  println(['getLevel3':this])
        s
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
No signature of method: static TestTrait.getLevel3() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [ugly]
```

If **class** is used (instead of **trait**) - **not error**.

```
...
TestClass.getLevel1() // no error
class TestClass extends TestTrait{}

class TestTrait{
...
}
```

Comment: Looks like this will be fixed in Groovy 4.0.18
https://github.com/apache/groovy/commit/e0a2db64d3eca236b6e0d34d358e1ebb021123db
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-11267